# Interpret Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Result in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am doing a Wilcoxon rank sum test (aka Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney) with R. There are two variables "ScorePerView", that is metric and "HasCodeElement", that is binary.

So the syntax is like that

> wilcox.test(ScorePerView ~ HasCodeElement, data=Datenmatrix, paired=FALSE, alternative='less')

When the result is significant (p-value < 0.005), then one distribution is lower or equal to the other.

But which one is lower?
Is the one where HasCodeElement is 0 is lower (or equal) then the one where HasCodeElement is 1.
Or is it the other way where HasCodeElement is 1 is lower (or equal) then the one where HasCodeElement is 0.

How can I interpret the R output on an one tailed test?

Here is my result with the syntax above.

[image]

Found the answer here:
[How do I interpret the Mann-Whitney U when using R's formula interface](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65566/how-do-i-interpret-the-mann-whitney-u-when-using-rs-formula-interface)

Also marked the Question as duplicated.

Comment: Thanks for going to the effort involved in finding the answer yourself and marking the question as a duplicate; this helps to make our site work better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use the formula interface with `~`. If you look at the syntax of the function `wilcox.test` [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) you will see that you can also separate your two samples as `x` and `y` and use `wilcox.test(x,y,...)`. This will remove any ambiguity. If you use `wilcox.test(x,y,paired=FALSE,alternative="less")`, and the p-value is significant, then it means that `x` and `y` come from different populations, and that `y` comes from a population with larger values than `x`.

Comment: My problem is totally different. I have a metric and a binary variable. And they are not paired. It is like this: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/non-parametric-methods/mann-whitney-wilcoxon-test. But I also want to know the direction.

Comment: I corrected my answer at the same time your wrote your comment I guess. And I was proposing to split `x` into `x` and `y` based on your binary factor